# SharePoint 2013: download entire directory in Document Library?

Tags: workflow, document-library, download, directory

Is it possible in `SharePoint 2013` to download an entire directory (folder) in a `Document Library` with its contents?

I did not find a button in the ribbon for that. Maybe it would be possible with a workflow?

---

`Open with Explorer` is not an option for "political" reasons. In other words, the users shall not be aware about this feature (although it technically works) to avoid them downloading large amounts of data at once.

Comment: "Open with Explorer" and then copy-paste should do it

Comment: what is directory?

Comment: sorry, with "directory" I meant a folder in a document library which contains documents and/or sub-folders

Comment: Have you tried using OneDrive for Business client?

Comment: yes, I did try out the `OneDrive for Business` client. I have a lot of problems syncing, it is not reliable.

Answer (score 2):

You could map a network drive to the library. In windows explorer, right click on Local Disk and select Map Network Drive. Click the "Connect to a web site" link. In the Add Network Location Wizard, Choose a custom network location, then enter the URL of your library.

Answer (score 2):

I could be misunderstanding, but "'political' reasons" would imply that the browser allowed does not support this feature (No IE).  What Erin L said is true.  But if you are not allowed to map a drive, in Windows explorer perform the following changes to the URL

```
http://yourfunkysite.com/sub-site/docLib/view/allitems.aspx
```

becomes

```
\\yourfunkysite.com\sub-site\docLib
```

It is basically explorer view coming from the client.  This will connect using WebDAV instead of through a browser and may prompt for auth.

Comment: I added an explanation in the question about the "Political reasons". It might be hard to explain/understand, but the users shall not be actively informed about the option to connect the document library like a local drive and then be able to download all the files at once. Nevertheless, it is technically possible.

Comment: So I guess I'm confused about the question.  Are you asking so you can prevent the downloading of files in bulk?  Or are you asking for a way to make explorer view more accessible?

Comment: sorry for creating the confusion in my question: in fact I'm searching for a way to download a directory via the SharePoint web interface **without revealing** the (even more comfortable) way of connecting an entire library as a shared drive.

Comment: I guess the answer you are looking for is "SharePoint doesn't do that".  Microsoft allowed Explorer if that functionality is required.  But I found some leads to third-party apps.
http://blog.bonzai-intranet.com/analysthq/2012/10/download-multiple-documents-for-sharepoint-2010/